# Excel VBA - UDF text replace

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to replace any text in square brackets, including them  – "[]" in a cell by emptiness with UDF:

```html
Function RMV(iCell As Range) As Variant
RMV = Replace(iCell.Value, "[*]", "")
End Function
```

But I guess the asterisk ("*") does not work here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression substring replacement in Microsoft Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/999983/11683)

Comment: @GSerg - Thanx for the idea, but I have no experience of use RegExp.

Comment: You have tried to use `*` as a pattern for "everything." That *is* regexp.

Comment: @GSerg - OK, I understand, but why this works correctly: Selection.Replace What:="[*]", Replacement:="" ?

Comment: Because Excel interface provides [rudimentary support](https://superuser.com/q/630692/52365) for regular expressions, and that is the method that is behind it. You can't expect same behaviour from other methods that also happen to be named `Replace`.

Comment: @GSerg - Thank you for the explanations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use reGex, you could use this as Function, remember to [enable Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43128681/7690982)

```
Function RMV(iCell As Range) As Variant
    Dim regEx As Object: Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") 'If Error Set regEx  = New regexp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    strPattern = "\[\]|\[.+?\]|$"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = CStr(iCell.Value)
        strReplace = ""

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = False
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.test(strInput) Then
            RMV = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
        Else
            RMV = "Not matched"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Where the [ReGex test](https://regex101.com/r/Bvx2Tx/6) uses the `\[\]|\[.+?\]|$` expression. I am also new to Regex, so this expression can be optimized.

Comment: Thanks for help! But in some cases that pattern does not work [properly](https://regex101.com/r/Bvx2Tx/4).

Comment: Thanx again! Cool, but in a case when a cell contains only "[]", nothing is happened.

Comment: Just did tests on Regex101, going to fix the Excel code.

Comment: Thank you, danieltakeshi, I'll been waiting for the updates!

Answer (score 0):

In sub procedure, that works.

```
Sub RMV(rng As Range)
rng.Replace "[*]", ""
End Sub

Sub Test()
RMV Range("A2")
End Sub
```